# What is the AndroidX equivalent of support-compat library?

Tags: android, gradle, androidx

I'm trying to implement notifications following the example at https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification

However, the guide shows an implementation of

```
dependencies {
implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0"}
```

But when I try to add the dependency in my gradle file I get this error:

> Version 28 (intended for Android Pie and below) is the last version of the legacy support library, so we recommend that you migrate to AndroidX libraries when using Android Q and moving forward. The IDE can help with this: Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX..

So what is the AndroidX version of this library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be

```
implementation "androidx.core:core:1.3.2"
```

You can find a list of all the mapping to AndroidX at https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings